# ExtJs: load a single gird from two different APIs

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have two entities, sent from two different APIs, with a one to one relationship.

I want to load both models in the same grid panel. The problem is that I can only load one store. To load the other store, I attached a callback to the grid reload event which edits the grid DOM manually to insert data form the second store.

**My Question is: Can I load both the model and the association without using DOM hacks like I did?**

The entities from APIs look like this:

```
Get /Users/Details:
{ 
    "Id" : "55b795827572761a08d735ac", 
    "Username" : "djohns", 
    "Email" : "admin@mail.com", 
    "FirstName" : "Davey", 
    "LastName" : "Johns"
}
```

And:

```
Get /Users/Rights:
{ 
    "_id" : "55b795827572761a08d735ac", 
    "Status" : "Activated", 
    "Roles" : [
        "portal", 
        "dataApp"
    ]
}
```

Notice the same id, which is used in the API as the key/foreign key).

Now these are the models:

```
Ext.define('Portal.model.users.UserRights', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    fields: [
        {
            name: 'id',
            mapping: 'Id'
        },
        {
            name: 'Status'
        },
        {
            name: 'UserId',
            mapping: 'Id',
            reference: 'Portal.model.users.UserDetails'
        }
    ],

    schema: {
        namespace: 'Portal.model.users',
        proxy: {
            type: 'rest',
            url: Portal.util.Util.constants.apiBaseURL + 'Users/Rights',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                rootProperty: 'Objects'
            }
        }
    }
});
```

And:

```
Ext.define('Portal.model.users.UserDetails', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        {
            name: 'id',
            mapping: 'Id'
        }, 
        'FirstName',
        'LastName',
        'Username',
        'Email'
    ],
});
```

And I defined a store for user details (while the store of the user rights is inside its own model):

```
Ext.define('Portal.store.UsersDetails', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    model: 'Portal.model.users.UserDetails',
    proxy: {
        type: 'rest',
        url: Portal.util.Util.constants.apiBaseURL + 'Users/Details',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: 'Objects'
        }
    }
});
```

Here is how I configured the Grid:

```
Ext.define('Portal.view.users.UsersGrid', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',

    store: 'UsersDetails',

    columns: [
        {
            dataIndex: 'id',
            text: 'Id'
        },
        {
            dataIndex: 'Username',
            text: 'Username'
        },
        {
            dataIndex: 'Email',
            text: 'Email'
        },
        {
            dataIndex: 'FirstName',          
            text: 'First Name'
        },
        {
            dataIndex: 'LastName',
            text: 'Last Name'
        },         
        {
            text: "Status",
            cls: "status-column",
            renderer: function (value, meta, record) {
                return "loading...";
            }
        }
    ],

    loadUserRights: function () {
        var columns = this.getEl().select('.status-column');
        var cells = this.getEl().select(".x-grid-cell-" + columns.elements[0].id + " .x-grid-cell-inner");
        data = this.getStore().getData();

        Ext.each(data.items, function (record, index) {
            var userRights = record.userUserRights();
            userRights.load({
                callback: function (records, operation, success) {
                    if (success) {
                        cells.elements[index].innerText = userRights.data.items[0].data.Status;
                    }
                }
            });

        });
    }
});
```

And then I load the gird from an external function:

```
grid.getStore().reload({
    callback: function (records, operation, success) {
        grid.loadUserRights();
    }
});
```